# Reading characters line by line from a file into 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble putting characters into a 2d array from a file. When I print out the array, I get `null`, and I cannot figure out why.

The program reads in a file, formatted with the first line containing 2 numbers, corresponding to height and width respectively, It first checks to see if the command line arguments are valid. If they are, it reads the file, creates a 2d array based on the two numbers, and then stores the rest of the file into the array. The rest of the file is a maze of characters, like this:

```
2 3
+-+-+-+
|S|   |
+ + + +
|   |E|
+-+-+-+
```

So, the 2d array mimics the maze structure. The method `readMazeFile` is where I am struggling.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MazeSolver {

   // The name of the file describing the maze
   static String mazefile;
   static int width;
   static int height;
   static int arrayWidth;
   static int arrayHeight;
   static char[][] mazeArrays;   
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      if (handleArguments(args)) {

         readMazeFile(mazefile, arrayHeight, arrayWidth);
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mazeArrays));
         //DrawMaze.draw(mazeArrays, height, width);

         if (solveMaze())
            System.out.println("Solved!");
         else
            System.out.println("Maze has no solution.");
      }
      else {
      System.out.println("The arguments are invalid.");
      }
   }

   // Handle the input arguments
   static boolean handleArguments(String[] args) {
      if (args.length > 4 || args.length < 1) {
         System.out.println("There are too many or too few command line arguments");
         return false;
      }
      if (args.length == 1) {
         mazefile = args[0];
         File file = new File(mazefile);
         if (!file.canRead()) {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
      if (args.length == 2) {
         mazefile = args[0];
         File file = new File(mazefile);
         if (!file.canRead()) {
            return false;
         }
         int cellsize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         if (cellsize < 10) {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
      if (args.length == 3) {
         mazefile = args[0];
         File file = new File(mazefile);
         if (!file.canRead()) {
            return false;
         }
         int cellsize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         int borderwidth = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
         if (borderwidth < 5) {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
      if (args.length == 4) {
         mazefile = args[0];
         File file = new File(mazefile);
         if (!file.canRead()) {
            return false;
         }
         int cellsize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         int borderwidth = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
         int sleeptime = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
         if (sleeptime < 0 || sleeptime > 10000) {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
      }   
      return false;
   }

   // Read the file describing the maze.
   static void readMazeFile(String mazefile, int arrayHeight, int arrayWidth) throws FileNotFoundException {

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(mazefile));
      height = scanner.nextInt();
      width = scanner.nextInt();
      arrayHeight = 2 * height + 1;
      arrayWidth = 2 * width + 1;
      char[][] mazeArrays = new char[arrayHeight][arrayWidth];
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println(line);
         for (int row = 0; row < arrayHeight; row++) {
           for (int col = 0; col < line.length(); col++) {
               mazeArrays[row][col] = line.charAt(col);




           }
         }



      }

   }

   // Solve the maze.      
   static boolean solveMaze() {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
+-+-+-+
|S|   |
+ + + +
|   |E|
+-+-+-+
null
Solved!
```

Thanks for the help and I apologize for any amateur flaws, I'm trying to learn Java. I would like to keep it in this structure. After this, I must use the 2d array to animate a solution to the maze with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

return array from readMazeFile and assign it in same array as :

```
mazeArrays = readMazeFile(mazefile, arrayHeight, arrayWidth);
```

chage return type to char[][]

```
static char[][] readMazeFile(String mazefile, int arrayHeight, int arrayWidth) throws FileNotFoundException
```

You are getting null because you are having mazeArrays as class variable as well as local variable so value has been updated to local variable not class variable. so you need to return mazeArrays array and you have assign in mazeArrays in main method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with this line:

```
    char[][] mazeArrays = new char[arrayHeight][arrayWidth];
```

Basically, when you later modify your `mazeArrays` variable you are overwriting this local variable rather than the static variable outside your method. Deleting the `char[][]` will solve your problem.

(Like this)

```
    mazeArrays = new char[arrayHeight][arrayWidth];
```